# ATG catalog export error in startSQLRepository

Tags: export, catalog, atg

I want to export the catalog data from `atg` production. I followed the steps as below.

1. create `FakeXADatasource.properties` file in `C:\ATG\ATG10.1.1\home\localconfig\atg\dynamo\service\jdbc.` (There is `mysql` user named **atguser** with password **atg123$**)

   ```
   $class=atg.service.jdbc.FakeXADataSource
   URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prod_lo
   user=atguser
   password=atg123$
   driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   ```
2. change `JTDataSource.properties` as below.

   ```
    $class=atg.service.jdbc.MonitoredDataSource

    dataSource=/atg/dynamo/service/jdbc/FakeXADataSource

    transactionManager=/atg/dynamo/transaction/TransactionManager

   loggingSQLInfo=false

    min=10

   maxFree=-1

    loggingSQLError=false

   blocking=true

    loggingSQLWarning=false

    max=10

   loggingSQLDebug=false
   ```
3. then run the "

> startSQLRepository.bat -m Store.Storefront -export all
>   catalogExport.xml -repository /atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalog"

command.

but while it processing it gives below error. Anyone know the reason or how to do a complete catalog export? (I have remove the last part of the error log because it exceeds the maximum length of 30000 characters. )

```
./startSQLRepository -m Store.Storefront -export all catalogExport.xml -repository /atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalog
```

Error:

> Error    /atg/dynamo/service/jdbc/JTDataSource   an exception was
>   encountered while trying to populate the pool with the starting number
>   of resources: atg.service.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)
>        Error    /atg/dynamo/service/jdbc/JTDataSource   The connection pool failed to initialize propertly, i.e. the starting number of
>   connections could not be created; check your database accessibility
>   and JDBC driver configuration 
>        Error    /atg/dynamo/service/IdGenerator CONTAINER:atg.service.idgen.IdGeneratorException;
>   SOURCE:CONTAINER:atg.service.idgen.IdGeneratorException;
>   SOURCE:java.sql.SQLException:
>   atg.service.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: java.sql.SQLException:
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) 
>        Error  /atg/dynamo/service/IdGenerator   at atg.service.idgen.PersistentIdGenerator.initialize(PersistentIdGenerator.java:389) 
>        Error  /atg/dynamo/service/IdGenerator   at      atg.service.idgen.AbstractSequentialIdGenerator.doStartService(AbstractSequentialIdGenerator.java:643)

Answer (score 0):

try setting max and min poolsizes to 1 and 5

Also make sure your DB is up and running and can be connected to

-DC21

Answer (score 0):

the configuration you are given the startSQLRepository is not taking is at runtime because it is still saying using password no and second error is with you connection pool. my suggestion is for you that try to change only to FakeXADatasource.properties file with username and password. I tried with the same configuration and able to export.